# Mysqldump couldn't excute show fields

Tags: linux, mysql

i am trying to create a mysql dump file but i  am having major issues:

firstly i tried:

```sh
mysqldump --user=root --password=**** --host=localhost system_db > /var/www/system_db/site/resources/backup/file.sql
```

Here i got the message:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1449: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

Then i tried to update the user:

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'root@localhost' WHERE definer='root@%'
```

And ran the statement again but without luck.

Then i tried:

```sh
mysqldump --single-transaction -u root -p system_*** > db.sql
```

This worked but now i get the following error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `v_user_stats`': SELECT command denied to user ''@'%' for column 'user_id' in table 'test_score' (1143)
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on? and how i can fix it?

Comment: @rajasimon how do i do that?

Comment: seems like mysqldump bug where it doesn't use invoker (root) privileges but definer ones: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `SHOW OPEN TABLES;` if you find out In_use is greater than 0 then that table is locked ....

I think the command to unlock is `UNLOCK TABLES`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The table is opened (in_use = 0), but still can't execute SHOW FIELDS. In the same time I can execute SHOW CREATE VIEW, and have ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*